# How are geneticists able to isolate gene functions?

Tags: genetics, genomics, dna-sequencing

As an example, this [Scientific American article](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/observations/2013/01/24/adaptation-to-starchy-diet-was-key-to-dog-domestication) describes a known area in the dog genome that metabolizes carbohydrates.

How is it that researchers are able to determine specific functions such as this?

Comment: Lots of ways. Gene knockout, gain of function, biochemical assays, etc...

Comment: @LanceLafontaine if you have a more detailed answer, please submit it as an answer rather than a comment.

Answer (score 3):

@LanceLafontaine suggested a few ways above, but I would recommend reading [this section](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK26818/)
in Alberts' Molecular Biology of the Cell, which gives a more descriptive overview of some approaches, but even that is not exhaustive.

An extremely simplistic and also not exhaustive summary:

1. observe mutants, see what processes are disrupted, and map these back to particular mutations
2. mutate a gene and see what processes are disrupted
3. biochemical studies to see, for example, which proteins (which are gene products) interact *in vivo* and things like where they're localized, which may hint at function.
4. analyze structure of proteins, see [how similar they are to other proteins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homology_%28biology%29) with known function, and infer that the protein of interest probably has a similar function

EDIT: The link to Alberts is to the 2002 edition (which is free online; the latest edition of the textbook costs around $200), so things have come a long way since then, but the underlying approaches are still in use.